# Repair USB drive (read only)

Tags: usb

I have read the forum for possible solutions, but I haven't found one that works for me yet. Here is the issue. I was copying files from my SSD to my USB drive, and I removed the pendrive!; it was dumb, but I did it.
Now the pendrive is "read only" (and I can't mount it) and I don't know hot to fix it. I have tried with Disks, Gparted, with the terminal, and no luck so far. Any ideas will be appreciated.

[image: Disks]

[image: Gparted]

**EDIT 1:** I can't delete the partitions. The option doesn't even appear on disks, and on Gparted doesn't work. Updating with two more screenshots.

I will read the links provided by you guys and keep you updated if there is success or not. It is not a big issue the pendrive itself, I can buy another one if I wanted to. But the point of being a Linux user is precisely to do things by your own. Which is why I am trying to repair this USB drive. Thanks.

[image: Gparted - trying to delete the partition]
[image: Disks - showing options available for the drive]

**EDIT 2:** I did tried MKUSB, and it didn't work. A lot of text, which can be summarized in "read only" stuff

[image: MKUSB]

**EDIT 3**: I also tried to wipe it. Didn't work as well.

[image]

**Thoughts:** I did tried on my 2nd laptop (Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS). All the same. So I guess the pendrive is really dead after all. Anyway, I appreciate the help. Thanks.

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: Did you try deleting the existing partition in GParted and creating a new partition?

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: @everyone Please let's wait for OP to respond before marking it as a duplicate. It may not be a duplicate.

Comment: Most of the time I have flash drives fail, they fail forever.